# .live() function binds event to wrong DOM elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following code :

```
$('#id').find('select').live('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-button:first').click();
    }
});
```

Now, on a particular page, element with id='id' doesn't exists. When I open a jQuery UI dialog with some other id, and press enter key on a select list within the dialog, the click event of first .ui-button gets triggered. Why ?

Comment: There must be an element with id='id' inside the dialog.

Comment: @Wilmer, no there isn't any element with id='id' inside dialog.

Comment: Is there an element with that id at any time in the page?

Comment: @Wilmer, that element appears on page when user clicks a particular link. Also, that is a separate div. Why the keypress event is bound to all dialogs ?

Comment: put a `console.log('select-keypres')` or something inside this event function and see if it's even getting called... possibly the button is getting clicked as a default.

Comment: @ashutosh because that element is wrapping the dialogs maybe it's missing a close tag ex: </div>

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `ON` function?

```
$( "body" ).on( "keypress", "#id select", function(event) {
  ...
});
```